# JavaScript inline object manipulation class & function conflict

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to create a inline class that get's element id in it's constructor, and call immediately to sub-function of this class.

I'm getting `styleit not a function`: but it's a class.

But I need it acting as function, just like jQuery does:

```
$('.hidden').show();
```

This is my code:

```
var styleit = function(elem) {
    this.el = document.getElementById(elem);

    this.green = function() {
        this.el.style.color = 'green';
    }

    this.red = function() {
        this.el.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

Activate like this:

```
<a href="#" id="theid" onclick="styleit('theid').green();">style me</a>
<a href="#" id="theid2" onclick="styleit('theid2').red();">style me</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead (this is how jQuery implements its $):

```
window.styleit = function(x) {

    return new _styleit(x);

};
```

***[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YUjdn/)***